# How to measure time from interaction until the browser has painted with Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, performance, browser, puppeteer, requestanimationframe

I'm using Puppeteer to create a user flow. I'm trying to measure the time from `click` to the rendered result on the page. I want to measure the whole duration of the render pipeline with:

**JavaScript > Style > Layout > Paint > Composite**

I'm not navigating to another page on click or displaying another button, I'm only updating elements.

**How can I detect the end of the render pipeline?**

I tried many different approaches, such as waiting for a selector, MutationObserver, or listening on events, but nothing worked properly. I also tried to extract the important tasks from a page.tracing result, but that was too complicated, and I can't find an API to extract that.

I found articles like [measuring paint time](https://www.webperf.tips/tip/measuring-paint-time/), where `requestAnimationFrame` is used to measure this. But, in my case, combined with Puppeteer `requestAnimationFrame`, it's always too late.

For example, here is the part of the Code where I'm measuring the time with `requestAnimationFrame`, but when I'm generating a tracing report over that time I can see that the logged time is much too long.

```js
await page.evaluate(() => window.performance.mark('test_start'));

await page.click(selectorSort);
 
const measureFrame = await page.evaluate(() => new Promise((resolve) => {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            performance.mark('test_end')
            const measure = performance.measure('FrameTime', 'test_start', 'test_end');
            resolve(measure.duration);
        })
    })
}));
```

Is there an easy or easier way to measure that time, or can someone explain to me why it won't work or what might be the best approach to try?